# how to send voice from lex bot to lambda using java in aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-java-sdk, aws-lex

I can able to send the text to my lambda function from lex bot and getting the response. But how to send the voice from bot to lambda and getting a response in voice or text format. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

The following blog written by AWS engineering team will definitely by helpful to address your problem.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/capturing-voice-input-in-a-browser/

Answer (score 0):

Following lambda function code returns voice from Bot.

```
 `public Object handleRequest(Map<String,Object> input, Context context) {

        context.getLogger().log("input" +input);
        LexRequest lexRequest = LexRequestFactory.createLexRequest(input);
        String content = String.format("<speak>Hi! Request came from:"+lexRequest.getBotName()+"</speak>",  

                lexRequest.getIntentName(),lexRequest.getCrust(),lexRequest.getPizzaKind(),lexRequest.getSize()

                );

        SessionAttributes sessionAttributes = new SessionAttributes();
        Message message = new Message("SSML",content); 

        DialogAction dialogAction = new DialogAction("Close", "Fulfilled", message);
        return new LexRespond(sessionAttributes,dialogAction);
    }`
```